# Perturbation Theory: Derivative of a trace.

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, trace, perturbation-theory

The problem that I am looking at is the following perturbation problem from the notes on [Trace Inequalities and Quantum Entropy](http://www.ueltschi.org/AZschool/notes/EricCarlen.pdf) on page 12, the following result is said to follow "by the Spectral Theorem and first order perturbation theory":

Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function on $(0,\infty)$ and $B,C$ self-adjoint (complex) $n \times n$ matrices. Then 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left|_{t=0}\right.\operatorname{Tr}[f(B + tC)] = \operatorname{Tr}[f'(B)C].$$

If someone knows a reference where I can learn why this is true (preferably an article, I could find online or through a University library), then that would be great.

Note: I already received a solution to this using some more powerful perturbation theory [$C^1$ unitarily diagonalizing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2890595/continuously-differentiably-unitarily-diagonalizing-b-tc-for-b-c-hermi), but I was wondering about less complicated things.

Comment: Considering how a trace is simply a sum of terms, the total time derivative evaluated at $t=0$ would just slide into the trace operation. From here, it's simply an extension on the chain rule

Comment: Sure... just why does there exist a chain rule for functions defined via the spectral theorem. Maybe, I would need to prove a version of the convergence lemma in Baby Rudin, where I approximate $f'$ by polynomials that have some antiderivatives that converge to $f$ and then I can try to interchange the derivative limit and the limit of polymonials for which the chain rule obviously applies.

Comment: For instance, if $f(x) = x^2$, then we know that $f(B + tC) = B^2 + t(BC + CB) + t^2C^2$ so its derivative in $t$ at zero is $BC + CB$ which does not equal $f'(B)C = 2BC$ in general, but does after applying the trace.

Comment: Yes, but since ${\rm tr}(CB)={\rm tr}(BC)$ you can combine the terms to obtain ${\rm tr}(2BC)$.

Comment: Yes, I agree. What I am saying is that for polynomials $f$, I can see that it works because under the trace, everything commutes. However, for a general continuously differentiable function I am not sure if one can make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The result is easy to check if $f(x)$ was a polynomial. For a general continuously differentiable function $f(x)$ and a given $\epsilon>0$, choose a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $|f(x)-p(x)|+|f'(x)-p'(x)|<\epsilon$ on an interval $I$ containing all of the eigenvalues of $B$ and $C$. One has
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}Tr(p(B+tC))(0)=Tr(p'(B)C),$$
and so for
$$g(t)=|Tr(p(B+tC))-Tr(p(B))-Tr(p'(B)C)t|$$
we have $g(t)/t \rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow 0$. 
First note that $$|Tr(p'(B)C)-Tr(f'(B)C)|=|Tr((p'(B)-f'(B))C)| $$ $$\leq \|p'(B)-f'(B)\| \|C\|<n \epsilon \|C\|.$$
Moreover,
$$|Tr(p(B+tC))-Tr(f(B+tC))|=|Tr(p(B+tC)-f(B+tC))|<n \epsilon,$$
and similarly 
$$|Tr(p(B))-Tr(f(B))|<n \epsilon.$$
Putting all these inequalities together, we have

$$h(t)=|Tr(f(B+tC))-Tr(f(B))-Tr(f'(B)C)t|\leq g(t)+(2+\|C\|)n\epsilon,$$
By letting $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, we have $0\leq h(t)\leq g(t)$ which implies the formula.

Comment: I'm fine up until getting $h(t) \leq g(t)$, because this inequality depended on $\|p - f\| < \epsilon$ and $g = g_p$. Once $\epsilon < \|p - f\|$ the inequality is false. You would need to control $g_p(t)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.